# Responsive absolute image scaling

Tags: html, css, image, resize, scaling

Why resize didn't work? (#mainContainer img)

```
#mainContainer
{
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
}

#mainContainer img
{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

And i got this: http://idlecoin.tk/ (try resize window(browser))
I try everything(Maybe).. And this didn't work. Again.. Again.. and Again..

.. I try make this site responsive.

Comment: My css code: https://pastebin.com/pWSMcBwd

Answer (score 0):

It's because your images have inline styles applied to them.

change this

```
<img src="img/xpmx.png" width="250px" height="250px">
```

to this

```
<img src="img/xpmx.png">
```

And use:

```
#mainContainer img{
  width:100%;
  max-width:250px;
}
```

Inline styles will always take priority over any other css. Inline styles are often added by javascript.